# Javascript UTC to Local (IST)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, time

I need to show messaging time in format 'h:mm a' (AngularJS date filter).
When I console my UTC time (got from server) to local it gives me

```
 Mon Apr 11 2016 18:29:41 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

And current local time

```
Mon Apr 11 2016 18:36:43 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

So when i display my date, it is as in format `6:29 PM` . Why it shows 7 minutes difference ?

Edit : Here is my code :

```
$http.get('/getmessage?id='+message.paidmessage).success(function(data){
  if(data.value != 1){
  console.log(new Date(data.Created_at) , new Date())
  $scope.Comments.push(data)
 }
})
```

Comment: _And current local time_ means current time in IST is it _Mon Apr 11 2016 18:41:43 GMT+0530 (IST)_ now ?

Comment: yes.. in IST @Niklesh

Comment: please cross check with your local server : http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_IN.aspx

Comment: same as my pc time @Niklesh

Comment: Can you also share angular code regarding this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108823/discussion-between-priyanka-and-niklesh).

Comment: Are you still getting 7 min difference and what is value of _data.Created_at_ ?

Answer (score 0):

try this 
    {{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}

'medium': equivalent to 'MMM d, y h:mm:ss a' for en_US locale (e.g. Sep 3, 2010 12:05:08 PM)

final your HTML will look like:-

```
{{obj.date| date:'medium'}}
```